# Why is my property nil when setting it using self.propertyname instead of _propertyname

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

In the `viewDidLoad()` below, setting my property with `self.textToAnalyze` results in the `property` being `nil` in the debugger, while setting the property directly using `_textToAnalyze` shows that the property is no longer nil. Why is this?

```
//
//  TextStatsViewController.m
//  colorSwitcher

#import "TextStatsViewController.h"

@interface TextStatsViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *colorfulCharactersLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outlinedCharactersLabel;

@end

@implementation TextStatsViewController

-(void)setTextToAnalyze:(NSAttributedString *)textToAnalyze
{

}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    _textToAnalyze=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor],NSStrokeWidthAttributeName :@-3}]; //setting it here with the underscore shows that this property is not nil in the debugger
  //self.textToAnalyze=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"test" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor],NSStrokeWidthAttributeName :@-3}];  //setting it here with the accessor shows that this property is nil in the debugger
}

-(void)updateUI
{
    self.colorfulCharactersLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d colorful characters",[[self charactersWithAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName] length]];

    self.outlinedCharactersLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d outlined characters",[[self charactersWithAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName] length]];
}
-(NSAttributedString *)charactersWithAttribute:(NSString *)attributeName
{
    int index=0;
    NSMutableAttributedString* characters=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    while(index < [self.textToAnalyze length])
    {
        NSRange range;
        id value = [self.textToAnalyze attribute:attributeName atIndex:index effectiveRange:&range];
        if(value)
        {
            [characters appendAttributedString:[self.textToAnalyze attributedSubstringFromRange:range]];
            index=range.location+range.length;
        }else{
            index++;
        }
    }
    return characters;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self updateUI];
}
@end


//
//  TextStatsViewController.h
//  colorSwitcher


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextStatsViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSAttributedString* textToAnalyze;
@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have an empty setter.

```
-(void)setTextToAnalyze:(NSAttributedString *)textToAnalyze
{

}
```

when you do `self.textToAnalyze = something` is the same of doing `[self setTextToAnalyze:something]`, so the instance variable is never set.

Change your custom implementation like this:

```
-(void)setTextToAnalyze:(NSAttributedString *)textToAnalyze
{
    _textToAnalyze = textToAnalyze;
}
```

or simply remove it, assuming that you have declared `textToAnalyze` as a @property in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSAttributedString *textToAnalyze;
```

(moreover, the property must be strong if you want the passed value to be retained)

Comment: Best to remove the custom setter entirely.  Custom setter/getter implementations are generally a sign of convoluted design.  Setters and getters should be dead simple -- should be the default synthesized behavior -- and any business logic related to mutation should be kept separate.

Comment: @bbum It's an interesting insight. But, what if I need to invalidate my custom view on its property change? Should I observe the change via e.g. KVO — eventhough that's my own property — and invalidate my view from the observer's method? That looks convoluted to me also when I can just implement my custom setter with some checks and `setNeedsDisplay` invokation if necessary. What do you think?

Comment: @AlaksiejN. You'll generally be better off with such logic at the point of the set.  That is, it is oft better to make a pass making the various state changes, then go tell everything to update their visual state based on the current contained state.   If you have each object trigger re-calculation of render state based on every property change, you'll quickly end up with a massive performance bottleneck caused by a slew of unnecessary calculations.

Comment: @AlaksiejN. Simple example;  a Person object has `firstName` and `lastName`.  They are sometimes, but not always, changed one after the other.  If you had an observer of `firstName` that recalculates stuff, then an observer on `lastName` that recalculates an overlapping set of stuff, then you'll end up doing unnecessary work.  *But* you still need to trigger a recalculation if only one is changed, which drives to the point of moving the "done making changes, update visual state" logic outside of the primitive classes/properties.